# how to get PIL for python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to run a python code which uses `tensorflow 1.15`, `keras 2.2.4` and `PIL 7.2.0`. I do not have PIL on my conda virtual environment running with Python 3.6. None of the following works for me-

```
conda install PIL 
conda install PIL=7.2
pip install PIL
pip install PIL==7.2
```

I have ralized that `conda install Pillow=7.2` or `pip install Pillow==7.2` may install PIL. Is this the right thing to do?

I just wanted to be sure, I do not want to get into version conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing the PIL Library, you have to run the command `pip install Pillow`. Refer [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

Comment: for version 7.2?

Comment: Run `pip install Pillow==7.2`

Comment: Glad to help @pkj